# How to write less than (in IBM CPLEX)

Tags: range, cplex

I am writing a code in cplex.

```
forall (l in Line) {

   (0.5<d_fic[lineconect[l].fromnode]<=1.0)    => (0.5<alpha[l]<=1.5);

}
```

the error that I am getting - (Function operator<.<=(float,dvar float+,float) not available in context CPLEX).

How to write code in CPLEX to define the range of variable in (0.5 1] i.e. I want to exclude 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

In

0.5<alpha[l]<=1.5

Change < into <=

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a strict inequality in LP and MILP models. If you want to exclude the 0.5 value you will need to do something like:

```
0.5 + epsilon <= alpha[l] <= 1.5
```

for some small value of epsilon, maybe 10e-5 or smaller.